# How to create a scope for current_user.following?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here are my User and Relationships models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: passive_relationships, source: :follower
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User", counter_cache: :followeds_count
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User", counter_cache: :followers_count
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
  validates :followed, uniqueness: { scope: [:follower, :followed] }
end
```

In Users Controller I can do:

```
@users = current_user.following
```

However I would like to turn this into a scope in my User model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you may approach:

1. Find all users who are following someone

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     scope :following_to, -> (user_id) {
       where(
         "id IN ( SELECT followed_id 
                  FROM relationships
                  WHERE follower_id = ?
                )",
         user_id
       )
     }
   end
   ```
2. Find all users who are following anyone, that means they are a follower

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     scope :follower, -> {
       where("id IN ( SELECT followed_id FROM relationships)")
     }
   end
   ```

Finally, you can use these scope as your expectation:

```
# Find all users who are following to User (id = 1)
User.following_to(1)

# Find all users who are following someone, 
# aka they are a follower
User.follower
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the Instance Method you can make a method For User Model

like this :

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def following?
   self.following.present?
  end

 end
```

By Using Scope you can call only the activerecord based query into the scope of model.

Answer (score 1):

You should get also this way

```
scope :following?, lambda { |user|
    {  user.following.present?    }
```

And this should be call like in your controller

```
User.following?(current_user)
```